# mentioning MOOC's I took in my scholarship application

Tags: masters, application, funding, mooc

I'm preparing my application for a master degree scholarship, would it help to put the MOOC's I took in the application, I earned five MOOC certificates and expecting another two in the near future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Why not? It shows that you go beyond what is required of you, and you have a genuine interest in learning. I always list certificates from MOOCs.

Answer (score 14):

FWIW, I put the MOOCs I've completed in my tenure portfolio as a professor and it actually went over really well. So yeah, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mention a brief comment about what the MOOC means (and means to you and what you liked about that college that offered the MOOC) in your letter of application.

I bet, the older you get, recent MOOC completion statements will be getting more informative to any reader/recipient of your application than grades from a, say, 10 year old college degree.